# Which kind of logic latch for an over-current H-Bridge disable?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, latch

I have a simple logic circuit requirement, but can't seem to match any standard flip-flop or latch to my needs (SR, JK, D, MS, level-sensitive or clocked, etc).

The circuit is to disable a H-bridge driver IC if an over-current situation is detected (via a Allegro ACS770 analog-output hall-effect current sensor input to a window comparator, creating the OverCurrent logic-level).

The DISable signal must stay active even if OverCurrent falls back to inactive, until the BridgeEnable is at least deactivated, or optionally deactivated and then reactivated.

**Inputs:**

BE (BridgeEnable), active-high.

OC (OverCurrent), active-high or active-low, I can flip the comparators either way.

**Output:**

DIS (Disable), ideally active-low.

This timing-diagram shows the functionality I'm looking for:
[image: Timing-Diagram needed]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard SR latch. When you make them out of 2 NOR gates, the 1,1 input state, often thought of as pathological to people just wanting a latch, actually performs the logic operation you are looking for.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPIZtQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll let you draw out the truth table properly and confirm that it does what you want.

Note that NOR1 always outputs 0 if overcurrent is true, regardless of what BE is doing. And DIS is active low!

Comment: duh!  thanks for that, can't believe I didn't invert the BE and see the truth-table resemblance to what I needed.  and yeah, the 'pathological' avoidance of two 1s (or 2 0s in a NAND S-R) isn't necessarily a deal-breaker, thank for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a D-register with an active low reset.  (Or active high reset and add an inverter).
 - Connect the data input high (1)
 - Connect the BE to the (active low) reset.
 - Connect the OC to the clock.